# how-to install pecl or pecl extention on Mac 10.6.7?

Tags: php, macos, macports, pecl

I install php5.3.6 with fpm + nginx + mysql by macports. But I can't find pecl or pecl_http in it.

I search and google it, but find nothing.

Some extention can be compiled and copy .so file to extention DIR. But I don't know how to compile pecl_http, there's no configure file.

How to get it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those that are available through macports are separate php5-* packages:

```
$ port list php5* | grep http
php5-http                      @1.7.0          php/php5-http

$ port list php5*
[lots of results...]
```